# App crashing when trying to switch to different fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I have a game application that has 2 different fragments. The first is a welcome/instructions page with a button to, "Start Game". The second is the game itself, containing a button, "New Game" which is supposed to take the user back to the original fragment. The button works fine as far as creating a new game in the game class and erasing all scores, etc. but when I add the code to switch back to the "Opening Fragment" it crashes. Thanks in advance! Tried to find a similar question but didn't have luck, also am new to android programming so any explanations are always appreciated!

```
public class GameFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    private Button newGame;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState){
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_fragment, container, false);
            getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.game_fragment);

            newGame = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.newGameButton);
            newGame.setOnClickListener(this);

            return view;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        case R.id.newGameButton:
            // Replace GameFragment with OpeningFragment
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.rootLayout, new OpeningFragment()).commit();
            break;
            // rootLayout is the id of the main activity layout
    }

}
```

here is the layout XML for the main activity and the game fragment.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment android:name="com.example.pig.OpeningFragment"
              android:id="@+id/opening_fragment"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.pig.GameFragment"
              android:id="@+id/game_fragment"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the game fragment xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/piggy" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player1Label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player_1_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spaces12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/spaces12" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player2Label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player_2_label" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player1NameView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player_1_name_view" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/spaces12" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player2NameView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player_2_name_view" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scoreLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/score" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/spaces16" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score2Label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/score" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player1ScoreView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player_1_score_view" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/spaces24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player2ScoreView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player_2_score_view" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentPlayerNameView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/current_player_name_view" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/turn_label" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pointsLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/points_label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentPlayerPointsView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/curr_points" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dieImage"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/die_image"
            android:src="@drawable/die1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/endTurnButton"
            style="android:buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/end_turn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rollDieButton"
            style="android:buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/roll_die" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newGameButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/new_game" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/winner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/winner" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/winsLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wins" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/diePic"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/die_pic"
            android:src="@drawable/die1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Logcat complaints below

```
07-20 01:27:20.982: E/Trace(1034): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060000 for fragment OpeningFragment{535b6a9c #1 id=0x7f060000}
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): at   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:823)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): at   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-20 01:27:23.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1034):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please show your layout XML for your activity.

Comment: it is a good practice for this type of scenario leave the `Activity` monitor which will be Exhibiting fragment, so when you need a fragment is replaced by another, 
example: `FragmentA` by `FragmentB` but fragments and who asks `FragmentB` appears in its place: so you create a communication channel for Activity fragments, stating that she should replace it with `FragmentB`.

Comment: post your game_fragment xml

Comment: logcat would be very useful

Comment: xml files added @Code-Apprentice

Comment: xml files added @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: logcat added @MikelPascual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.game_fragment);
```

You are trying to change the layout of your activty layout to `game_fragment` layout which by then wont found the `.replace(R.id.rootLayout` because the layout of your activity is changed.

**solution:**

remove the `getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.game_fragment);` so you still have the `R.id.rootLayout` view when you replace a the fragment.

**EDIT:**

change it to this.

```
newGame = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.newGameButton);
newGame.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: If I do that the program crashes as soon as I try to switch from the Opening fragment to the Game Fragment. (Now it is only crashing when I've already gone from Opening to Game Fragment and then try to go back to Opening)

Comment: @user3192682 This is the answer to your question. If you have **other** problems, you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: Tried using view. instead of getActivity(). at first but this doesn't work and program crashes immediately. Null Pointer exception because doesn't have access to the widgets.

Comment: @user3192682 you have a complicated design. You actually dont need to change the layout of your activity, but use the view of your fragment that was inflated to get the view(button)

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Any way you can explain this more? I'm going off an example my professor gave us. As I said I'm new to android so I'm not sure what this means as far as how my code is overly complicated. Your help is really appreciated

Comment: `getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.game_fragment);` is flat out wrong. This is not the correct solution to your original problem. Please remove this and update your question with your current code and error or post a whole new question and we will continue to help you.

Comment: @user3192682 do as  Code-Apprentice is saying.

Comment: Made appropriate changes, everything is working now. Strange because this is how I had it originally and eclipse was complaining but I've noticed it does that sometimes and just needs to be restarted or to do a project clean. Everyone's help was very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have implementet your main_activity.xml is wrong

If you have a container (i.e. your id: rootLayout) you don't have to specify the fragments in the xml. You add/remove/replace them programmatically ( when doing so it's called dynamic fragments). In your example you have used both static and dynamic fragments.

Static is when you define the fragment in xml with `<fragment ../>` tags, with static fragments you dont have control over when to view and hide your fragment. Dynamic is when you have a layout which works as a container, and then you handle the fragments with the `FragmentManager`

And try post your code for the OpeningFragment & MainActivity